# Formatting Date to correct format in Power BI, Excel

Tags: excel, postgresql, powerbi, powerquery, data-analysis

How do you format date in power BI, excel, and PostgresSQL without changing other correct format.
It seems the 1st to 3rd column is on Day-Month-Year, it doesn't recognize by excel as date instead as a number
Thanks!

[image]

I tried delimiter on power BI and excel but it doesn't work to me. Maybe I'm just doing it wrong.
I tried this formula in excel but shows no value on the correct date format.

```
=IF(SEARCH("-",I2), SUBSTITUTE(I2,"-","/"))
```

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your dates are UK but Power Query is parsing as US and falling over on those dates which don't parse properly. In PQ, click the column header icon and then choose "Using Locale..."

[image]

Select Date and UK.

[image]